# SDK Integration in Nuxt3 error with Axeptio

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sdk, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I am currently working on a Nuxt3 project and I need to integrate a script delivered by Axeptio (cookie platform).

I made Nuxt3 plugin to use their script integration

```
export default defineNuxtPlugin((useNuxtApp) => {
  ;(<any>window).axeptioSettings = {
    clientId: '...',
    cookiesVersion: '...',
  }

  ;(function (d, s) {
    var t:any = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
      e: any = d.createElement(s)
    e.async = true
    e.src = '//static.axept.io/sdk.js'
    t.parentNode.insertBefore(e, t)
  })(document, 'script')
})
```

but this throws

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'REACT_APP_SC_ATTR')

So I tried in a Nuxt2 and it is working normally.

What can I do to make it work ?

Comment: Where is `REACT_APP_SC_ATTR`?

Comment: Okay I've found the issue. It was because ```process.env``` was undefined in Nuxt3

Comment: Hi, did my answer solved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Nuxt3 is based on Vite, hence not using `process.env` as Webpack4 (in Nuxt2).
[Here is](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-variables) how to access env variables in Nuxt3, by using `import.meta.env.YOUR_COOL_ENV_VAR`.

Comment: Hello kissu,
yes, your anwser is a solution that can be used.
For my case, I used `const config = useRuntimeConfig()` and `process.env = config`